# Do I control for different effects by adding the variables to the regression?

Tags: r, lm, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm trying to understand the dynamics of fixed effects in *R*.

Regression without FEs:

```
lm(return ~ esg_score + education, data = df)
```

Do I manage to control for:

- firm fixed effects
- industry by year fixed effects
- country by year fixed effects

By adding them to the regression as follows?

```
lm(return ~ esg_score + education + firm + industry*year + 
             country*year, data = df)

firm country year industry
 A     GE    2011 23
 B     GB    2011 23
 A     GE    2012 23
```

Comment: Yes - with that formula `firm` gives you a firm effect estimate. `industry*year` gives you estimates for each year, industry, and industry:year combination, and `country*year` gives you each country, year (already covered by `industry*year`, but fine to be here too) and country:year interaction effects.

Comment: alright, thank you for the answer, @GregorThomas!

Comment: In general, adding a variable to the RHS of a linear regression model "adjusts for it" or "controls for it". There are lots of other ways in other contexts to handle confounding variables: backdoor adjustment, frontdoor adjustment, instrumental variables, stratified analysis, and no doubt a few others.